# Add one column in one table

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have the following table with the following code:

```
\documentclass{cta-author}
\usepackage{mystyle}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{myrq}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% Acronyms
\input{acronyms}

% frames
\usepackage{framed}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,1}
\newenvironment{summary}[1]%
  {%
    \begin{shaded}%
    \iffalse\end{shaded}\fi
    \textbf{#1 Summary:}%
  }%
  {\end{shaded}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[t]
    \caption{Overview of \ac{slr} Coding Attributes}
    \label{tab:Coding_attr}
    \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\scriptsize\normalfont}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \centering
    \scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}{ c   c  c  c  c  c  c  c  }

  \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries\thead[t]{\textbf{Code Representation}\\ \textbf{Approach}}}&\smash{\bfseries\thead[t]{\textbf{Programming}\\ \textbf{Language}}} & \smash{\bfseries\thead[t]{\textbf{Code-Level}\\ \textbf{Granularity}}}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries\thead[t]{\textbf{Deep Learning}\\ \textbf{Architecture}}}\\
      \thead{\emph{Tree}\\ \emph{Based}}   & \thead{\emph{Graph}\\ \emph{Based}} & \thead{\emph{Token}\\\emph{ Based}} & \emph{Others} & & & \emph{DL Model} & \emph{Others}  \\ \hline

      \rule{0pt}{6ex}       AST & CFG & \makecell{Word\\ Embedding} & ByteCode & C   & \makecell{Method Level}    & ANN & DBN   \\
             & DFG & n-grams                     & ASCII    & C++ & \makecell{Statement level} & RNN & NMT   \\
             & PDG &                             & Code Gadget      & C\# &                              & LSTM & RL   \\
             & CallFG &                             & Latent Semantic Indexing      & Java &                              & CNN &       \\
             &     &                             & Binary Visualization      & Java Script &                              & GNN &       \\
             &     &                             &          & Python &                              & Auto-Encoder &       \\
             &     &                             &          &     &                              & Attention Mechanism &       \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

The output figure is the following

[image]

The first two lines are the headers and sub-header respectively.

Now I would like to change the table by adding a new column at the end "Software Task", with two subheaders, software tasks and others (like "Deep Learning Architecture". I tried to modify the code like the following:

```
 \begin{table*}[t]
    \caption{Overview of \ac{slr} Coding Attributes.}
    \label{tab:Coding_attr}
    \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\scriptsize\normalfont}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \centering
    \scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}{ c   c  c  c  c  c  c  c c c}

  \multicolumn{5}{c}{\bfseries\thead[t]{\textbf{Code Representation}\\ \textbf{Approach}}}&\smash{\bfseries\thead[t]{\textbf{Programming}\\ \textbf{Language}}} & \smash{\bfseries\thead[t]{\textbf{Code-Level}\\ \textbf{Granularity}}}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries\thead[t]{\textbf{Deep Learning}\\ \textbf{Architecture}}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries\thead[t]{\textbf{Software}\\ \textbf{Task}}}\\
      \thead{\emph{Tree}\\ \emph{Based}}   & \thead{\emph{Graph}\\ \emph{Based}} & \thead{\emph{Token}\\\emph{ Based}} & \emph{Others} & & & \emph{DL Model} & \emph{Others} & \emph{Task} & \emph{Others} \\ \hline

      \rule{0pt}{6ex}       AST & CFG & \makecell{Word\\ Embedding} & ByteCode & C   & \makecell{Method Level}    & ANN & DBN & Code Clone Detection & Code Suggestion  \\
             & DFG & n-grams                     & ASCII    & C++ & \makecell{Statement level} & RNN & NMT   \\
             & PDG &                             & Code Gadget      & C\# &                              & LSTM & RL   \\
             & CallFG &                             & Latent Semantic Indexing      & Java &                              & CNN &       \\
             &     &                             & Binary Visualization      & Java Script &                              & GNN &       \\
             &     &                             &          & Python &                              & Auto-Encoder &       \\
             &     &                             &          &     &                              & Attention Mechanism &       \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

The output is the following:

[image]

As you can see the Software Task main header goes in a new line above the sub-header tree-based column instead of being in the last main column.

Comment: I would start by changing `\begin{tabular}{ *{8}{c} }` to `\begin{tabular}{ *{10}{c} }`, as you need to create 2 extra columns, not just 1.

Comment: Please, completes your code fragments to compilable documents. Add all missed definitions and packages to document preamble. Where is available used documentclass?

Comment: @Mico Your proposed solution solves one part of the problem. But it still the problem of the main header which is "Software Task" ib bold

Comment: Consider , that we haven't your private packages (`mystyle`, etc.). Reduce preamble to what is necessary to produce your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote,

> Now I would like to change the table by adding a new column at the end "Software Task", with two subheaders, "Software tasks" and "Others"

Since you're looking to add **two** subheaders (and one new header cell that spans the two new subheaders), you must increase the number of columns by **two**, not one.

Incidentally, why did you change `\multicolumn{4}{c}{...}` to `\multicolumn{5}{c}{...}`?

I would like to recommend that you drastically declutter the appearance of the table by not using **boldfacing** and *italics* in the header and subheader cells. Next, I would also use the `booktabs` package (and, in particar, its `\cmidrule` macro) to impose a bit of recognizable visual structure on the headers and subheaders. Finally, do consider reducing some of the column widths by using abbreviations where possible.

[image]

```
\documentclass{cta-author}
\usepackage{makecell,booktabs}
\providecommand\ac[1]{#1} % ??

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}  % [t] % <-- [t] has no effect
    \caption{Overview of \ac{slr} Coding Attributes}
    \label{tab:Coding_attr}
    \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\scriptsize}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \centering
    \scriptsize

\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{@{} *{10}{c}  @{}} % before: \begin{tabular}{ *{8}{c} }
\toprule
    \multicolumn{4}{@{}c}{Code representation approach}
  & \thead[t]{Programming\\ language} & \thead[t]{Code-level\\ granularity}  
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead[t]{Deep learning\\ architecture}}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\thead[t]{Software\\ task}}
\\ 
\cmidrule(r){1-4} \cmidrule(lr){7-8} \cmidrule(l){9-10}
  \thead[t]{Tree\\based} & \thead[t]{Graph\\based} & \thead[t]{Token\\based} & Others 
  & & 
  & DL model & Others 
  & Task & Others  \\ 
\midrule
      
AST & CFG & \makecell[t]{Word\\embedding} & ByteCode & C & \makecell[t]{Method\\level}    
      & ANN & DBN  &  \dots & \dots \\ 
    & DFG & n-grams & ASCII & C++ & \makecell[t]{Statement\\level} 
      & RNN & NMT & \dots & \dots \\ 
    & PDG &   & Code Gadget & C\# & & LSTM & RL \\ 
    & CallFG &   & Lat.\ Sem.\ Indexing & Java &  & CNN & \\ 
    &     & & Binary Vis. & Java Script &  & GNN & \\ 
    &     & & & Python & & Auto-Encoder & \\ 
    &     & & & & & Attention Mech. & \\ 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `tabularray` package your table code can be quite a lot simplified. Beside this in below MWE the following changes are done:

- columns are of `X` type, consequently the table width is `\textwidth` and manual breaking text (except in the first table row) is not needed anymore
- used are rules from `booktabs` package
- used font size in table is increased to `\small`

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}%{cta-author} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
    \caption{Overview of \emph{slr} Coding Attributes}
    \label{tab:Coding_attr}
    \small
\begin{tblr}{colsep=3pt,
             colspec = {@{} *{2}{X[0.8,c,m]} 
                            *{2}{X[c,m]}
                            *{2}{X[1.2,c,m]}
                            *{2}{X[0.8,c,m]}
                            *{2}{X[1.2,c,m]}
                         @{}},
             row{1,2} = {font=\bfseries}
             }
    \toprule
\SetCell[c=4]{c}   {Code\\ representation approach} 
    &   &   &   & \SetCell[r=2]{c,m}  Program. language
                    & \SetCell[r=2]{c,m} Code-level granularity
                        & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {Deep learning\\ architecture}
                            &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {Software\\ task}
                                    &           \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-4} \cmidrule{7-8} \cmidrule[l]{9-10}
Tree based
    & Graph based
        & Token based
            & Others
                &   &   & DL model
                            & Others
                                & Task
                                    & Others    \\
    \midrule
AST
    & CFG
        & Word embedding
            & ByteCode
                & C & Method level
                        & ANN
                            & DBN
                                & Code Clone Detection 
                                    & Code Suggestion     \\
    & DFG
        & n-grams
            & ASCII
                & C++
                    & Statement level
                        & RNN
                            & NMT
                                & \dots
                                    & \dots     \\
    & PDG
        &   & Code Gadget
                & C\#
                    &   & LSTM
                            & RL
                                & \dots
                                    & \dots     \\
    & CallFG
        &   & Lat. Sem. Indexing
                & Java
                    &   & CNN
                            &   & \dots
                                    & \dots     \\

    &   &   &   &   &   & Attention Mech.
                            &   & \dots
                                    & \dots     \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]